# What are the appropriate equivalents of pointwise products/coproducts/exponentials for profunctors?

Tags: category-theory

Endofunctors in Set have easy pointwise products/coproducts/exponentials.

$
\begin{equation}
 \text{id}(x) = x \\
 (f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) \\
 \text{const}(c)(x) = c \\
(f \times g)(x) = f(x) \times g(x) \\
(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)\\
(f^c)(x) = f(x) ^c 
\end{equation}$

I don't think I ever explicitly saw the equivalents for profunctors.
I think they would be Yoneda like and convolution like?

Below I am following the convention the first parameter is covariant and the second is contravariant.

$\begin{equation}
 \text{id}(x, y) = x \rightarrow y \\
 (f \circ g)(x, z) = \Sigma y, f(x, y) \times g(y, z) \\
 \text{const}(c)(x, y) = y \rightarrow c 
\end{equation}$

Pointwise products/sums would be intersection/union like. Not sure of a standard notation.

$\begin{equation}
(f \cap g)(x, y) = f(x, y) \times g(x, y) \\
(f \cup g)(x, y) = f(x, y) + g(x, y) 
\end{equation}$

I think I can puzzle my way through the "correct" combinators. They would be Yoneda-fied and sort of convolutiony.

$
\begin{equation}
(f \times g)(x, y) = \Sigma u v, f(x, u) \times g(x, v) \times (y \rightarrow u \times v)\\
(f + g)(x) = \Sigma u v, f(x, u) \times g(x, v) \times (y \rightarrow u + v)\\
(f^c)(x, y) = \Sigma u, f(x, u) \times (y \times c \rightarrow u)
\end{equation}$

But how would I do these combinators with two sided discrete fibrations?

I like to think of spans as like parametric equations or like sequents.

You want some kind of lax pullback, not sure of how best to notate. It's imagined as a side condition like a strict pullback could be.

$\begin{equation}
 \text{id}(t) = \frac{t}{t} \\
 (\frac{P}{Q} \circ \frac{Q'}{R})(s, t) = \frac{P(s)}{R(t)} \: , Q(s) \rightarrow Q'(t)\\
\end{equation}
$

Not sure of a good notation but imagine all unification is via lax pullback.

$\begin{equation}
 \text{const}(c)(t) = \frac{t}{c} \\
\frac{P}{Q} \cap \frac{P}{Q} = \frac{P}{Q} \\
\frac{P}{Q} \cup \frac{R}{S} = \begin{cases}
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} , x \in \text{dom}(P) \\
\frac{Q(x)}{S(x)} , x \in \text{dom}(Q)
\end{cases} \\
\frac{P}{Q} \times \frac{P}{R} = \frac{P}{Q \times R} \\
\frac{P}{Q} + \frac{P}{R} = \frac{P}{Q + R} \\
(\frac{P}{Q})^c = \frac{P}{Q^c}
\end{equation}$

Anyhow I'm not quite sure about the "right" version of these combinators for profunctors and especially not for discrete fibrations.

Comment: Can you bracket $f^c$ in a less confusing way? There must be a mistake, because what you wrote is not covariant in $y$...

Comment: ...maybe you mean $\int^u F(x,u)\times y \times (c,u)$? If yes, this is just $y\times F(x,c)$ (but there's a problem: in what component is F contravariant? In this notation, there's no choice but F being covariant in x and contravariant in u; but then, it is covariant in x *and* in y...)

Comment: @fosco I'm sorry I used the opposite arrangement for variance. The first parameter being covariant and second contravariant. It's still possible I messed up variance somewhere. I always need to double check things to make sure I got variance right.